# Please help. Chrome 104 ruined everything; 105 changed nothing

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, youtube

Ever since Chrome updated itself to 104 on my Win7 laptop,
the UAC box always pops-up: "Do you want to allow Chrome
to make changes to this computer?"

If I click "Yes" and there's no Chrome window already open,
it sometimes takes 2 minutes for my startup page to appear
(which is just a simple blank "Google Search" window).

But what's really frustrating is anything related to YouTube.

Whether it's "youtube.com" or any link to a YouTube video,
a ***"Review name update"*** box pops-up and freezes everything,
then my "Physical Memory Usage" starts zipping upwards.

Here are 2 screenshots:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1wy1.jpg
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRA0N.jpg

Strangely enough, the exact same thing happens whenever
I click on a Twitter link:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/DregK.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmjJ8.png

This has been going on since the very beginning of August.

I don't dare click on "OK", nor "Uninstall app".   What app?   
This is a laptop, not a phone.   Also, I don't have a Twitter
account.   Which app includes both YouTube and Twitter?
Is there an app called ***"Review name update"***?

It's impossible to X-out the box, or even X-out the window.   
I always end up having to go to Task Manager to kill it off,
but even that refuses, and I have to 'force-close' the beast.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp6RT.png

I have no idea where this "1234 1324 ouisd riou 2o4098"
YouTube thing came from -- but oddly enough, last year
I did indeed save a Twitter link that's coincidentally called
"MTL embarrassing sidewalk":   https://i.stack.imgur.com/UECHk.png   https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiiBR.png

Why this should haunt me one year later, I have no clue.

---

Thus I did the only reasonable thing a sane human being
would do:   I did a "System Restore" back to Chrome 103.

Of course, that just made matters worse -- because now
Chrome wouldn't even open at all.   No Google anything.   
It's as though I had no internet.

Digging deep into my File Explorer, it turns out that I had
both Chrome 103 and 104 concurrently.

A few days later, I tried Firefox -- and no problems at all.   
I used it to get to Google, and it updated itself back to 104,
but also back to 'square 1' with the exact same problems.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrpY1.png

Chrome has now updated itself to 105, but everything is
still the same.

I've killed all extensions, but everything is still the same.   
I have gone "Incognito", but everything is still the same.   
I've scanned with Avast, but everything is still the same.

I've done a Google Search about "Review name update",
but seemingly nothing.   What gives?

Please paste the following into any Google Search box:   
"review name update" app

Comment: Avast isn't reliable, if you're going to check reviews. Try Malwarebytes to scan it. The description of your issue is 80% more likely a malware/script trying to highjack your pc. Worst, ransomware, it may explain why your pc resources is spiking because it encrypts something in the background. or Your last resort is clean windows reinstallation.

Comment: As mentioned, likely malware was installed into Chrome as an add-on, or otherwise in Windows 7. Since Windows 7 is *far* beyond end-of-life, consider another OS that *does* have security updates. If the laptop can't run Windows 10 or 11, try Linux, e.g., Ubuntu, that can be tested from USB without installation. Linux versions of Chrome and many other Windows apps are available, or their equivalent.

Comment: Chrome still offers support for Windows 7, until January 15, 2023. // Chrome supports Progress Web Apps (PWAs)—websites as applications (of sorts).